# Predicting Positional Displacement with a Bivariate Gaussian Distribution

Tags: computer-vision, statistics

In my computer-vision problem, a blob can move either forward or backwards (with a slight chance of moving sideways) along its directional axis. I am seeking a bivariate model because I need to determine whether a blob's new position (with respect to its old one) is "feasible," or "likely." However, the blob can not move extreme distances very quickly.

Thus, there is a high probability that the blob will not move very far if it does move (but still a sufficient amount such that the probability distribution will be elongated along one axis [not the orthogonal]).

I am searching for a model that has high probability values within a smaller region, but has a larger encompassing region with small (and distinctly different) probability values.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sounds like you might want a particle filter.

Comment: Im not sure I understand the question - you want a model (in other words, a 2D PDF), of the motion? I think in those types of problems, (histogram filters for example), the uncertainty matrix has to be specified. You then convolve it with your apriori PDF. Perhaps I have not understood you.